# Teradata query to Calculate Start and End dates Based on a condition

Tags: sql, teradata, lag, teradata-sql-assistant, lead

I have a dataset for certain STS codes and I need to retain the Start and End Date When `Status =03`

I have the following Data

```
HAVE

  ID               CHGDATE          STS
  101              11/21/2022        00
  101              11/22/2022        03
  101              11/23/2022        03
  101              11/24/2022        03
  101              03/08/2023        04
  102              08/05/2022        03
  102              08/08/2022        04
  102              11/10/2022        03
  102              11/17/2022        00

WANT
   ID            STARTDATE           ENDDATE
  101           11/22/2022           03/08/2023
  102           08/05/2022           08/08/2022
  102           11/10/2022           11/17/2022
```

- The ID 101 had `STS=03` for the fist time on 11/22/2022, hence this should be my '`StartDate` for this Record. This record changed its `STS` to other than `03` on 3/8/2023, therefore this should be `EndDate`
- The ID 102 had `STS=03` multiple times with two `Start` and `End` dates 8/5-8/8 and 11/10-11/17

  ```
   My query

    SELECT 
     ID,STS,CHGDATE AS STARTDATE,
     LEAD(CHGDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CHGDATE) AS ENDDATE
  FROM 
    HAVE
    WHERE STS=03
  ```

This query works for ID 102 but not for ID 101. Is there a different way to achieve the desired result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It won't work the way you're trying to do it.  Your query is excluding all rows where sts <> '03'. I would split it into 2 derived tables, one for your start dates (sts = 03), and one for everything else (sts <> '03'). Then you can join those together, and use qualify to get only the relevant rows:

```
create volatile table vt_foo
(
id int,
changedate date,
sts varchar(2))
on commit preserve rows;
insert into vt_foo values (102, '2022-08-05','03');
insert into vt_foo values (102, '2022-08-08','04');
insert into vt_foo values (102, '2022-11-10','03');
insert into vt_foo values (102, '2022-11-17','00');

select
strt.id,
strt.changedate as startdate,
oth.changedate as enddate
from 
(
select
*
from
vt_foo
where
sts = '03')  strt
left join
(
select
*
from
vt_foo
where
sts <>  '03') oth
    on strt.id = oth.id
    and oth.changedate > strt.changedate
qualify row_number() over (partition by strt.id,strt.changedate order by oth.changedate) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. For ID 101, The query is still giving all the three StartDates for instead of Just 11/22 and 03/08 as Start and End Dates

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
select ID,min(chgdate)startdate,max(nextdate)enddate,min(STS) STS,group_num
from(
  select *
    ,sum(new_group)
        OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CHGDATE
             ROWS_BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING -- @Fred
       ) group_num
  from(
    SELECT 
     ID,STS,CHGDATE,
     case when STS<>Lag(STS) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CHGDATE) then 1
     else 0 end new_group,
     LEAD(chgdate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CHGDATE) nextdate
    FROM HAVE  
  )t
)t2
where sts='03'
group by id,group_num
order by id,group_num
```

Comment: Thank you @ValNik.. This doesn't work for ID 102. It is creating the smae new_group for different records

Comment: Need to add `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` to the window clause get a cumulative SUM within a partition. Teradata defaults to `ROWS_BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`